How to inject tronclient into controller?
I am trying to make transactions on tron network in my controller, I am using tronsharp library for .NET 8.0.
This is my controller's constructor:
public TronController(DataContext context, ITronClient tronClient)
{
    _context = context;
    _tronClient = tronClient;
}

But I can't seem to inject it in my program.cs. When I try to do so, tronclient says that it's inaccessible.
This is how my db is injected
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);

This is how I am trying to inject the tron client:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITronClient>(provider =>
{
    var tronClient = new TronClient(new TronSharp.Protocol.TronSharpConfiguration
    {
        FullNodeUrl = "https://api.trongrid.io", // Mainnet URL
        SolidityNodeUrl = "https://api.trongrid.io",
        EventServerUrl = "https://api.trongrid.io"
    });
    return tronClient;
});

but tronclient says that its inaccessible even here

"tronclient says that its inaccessible" in what way are you seeing this error message?

return new TronClient(tronConfig);
here , when i hover over this erorr, it says "TronClient is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Because you are supposed to use an extension method to configure it? https://github.com/mziii/TronSharp?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration

that worked, thanks.
